# Iframe mobile responsivness

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, mobile

I have a page and I wanted more than one slide show on the same page but that proves slightly difficult with JavaScript variables so I decide to make each slide show an iframe. This works rather well however now the responsiveness of the iframe is causing issues. The slides within the Iframe are div elements that will stack based on screen size. The issue is now that the Iframe does not get longer. I have tried:

```
<iframe src="Web.html"  height="100%" frameborder="1" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

except that doesn't make the iframe long enough even before resizing. My question is, how do I make the Iframe as tall as the page is, and the page will be resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the resizeIframe function

```
  <iframe src="Other.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this);"></iframe>

 function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

}

Comment: this is not very helpful as you only show the onload, what about the function resizeIframe?

Comment: I added the JS apologies I forgot

Answer (score 2):

Try Bootstarp Responsive embed.

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is like: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however, that keeps the aspect ratio the same however when the iframe width gets smaller, the height needs to get longer because of the content, I can't have scrolling.